# Paypal Subscription Setup

Tags: html, git, curl, paypal

I am trying to setup my three subscriptions using curl and im making sure the values are correct. Trying to do a request and get a response but my curl is not functioning corectly.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create

My intention:

- 3 Plans to choose from: Elite (149 PHP/MONTH), Premium (349 PHP/MONTH), Luxury (549 PHP/MONTH)
- 1 month is 30 days as paypal said
- id like to set it to auto renew monthly until the customer chooses to cancel it.
- only one will be active at a time, if a user chooses another of the three while one is running, they will automatically be stopped getting billed and will be charged with the new one chosen. (eg: currently elite149, the subscription and renewal will change to 549luxury once chosen).

  ```
  curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -H "Authorization: Basic account_clientid:account_secretcode" \
   -H "PayPal-Request-Id: EPL-25012019-001" \
   -d '{
     "product_id": "MWC-2019EPL",
     "name": "My White Card Subscription Plans",
     "description": "MyWhiteCard Membership Levels",
     "status": "ACTIVE",

     "billing_cycles": [
       {
         "frequency": {
           "interval_unit": "MONTH",
           "interval_count": 1
         },
         "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
         "sequence": 1,
         "total_cycles": 999,
         "pricing_scheme": {
           "fixed_price": {
             "value": "149",
             "currency_code": "PHP"
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "frequency": {
           "interval_unit": "MONTH",
           "interval_count": 1
         },
         "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
         "sequence": 2,
         "total_cycles": 999,
         "pricing_scheme": {
           "fixed_price": {
             "value": "349",
             "currency_code": "PHP"
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "frequency": {
           "interval_unit": "MONTH",
           "interval_count": 1
         },
         "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
         "sequence": 3,
         "total_cycles": 999,
         "pricing_scheme": {
           "fixed_price": {
             "value": "549",
             "currency_code": "PHP"
           }
         }
       }
     ],

     "payment_preferences": {
       "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
       "setup_fee": {
         "value": "0",
         "currency_code": "PHP"
        },
       "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
       "payment_failure_threshold": 3
     },
     "taxes": {
       "percentage": "10",
       "inclusive": false
     }
   }'
  ```
- I just took out my account's client_id:secret
- Live credentials are being used

[image: live]

My questions and concerns:

1. In the access token, do I need to put the "access_token$production$" and then the code given?
2. Can I manually create the Paypal request id and the product id?
3. Will the billing cycles be all on the same command or do I have to trigger this three times?
4. Is the setup fee the charge if a customer subscribes? I first assumed that is the case and set it to 0.
5. My intention is to have the monthly subscription (30 Days) auto renew until the user unsubscribes. I set my example to 12 but will `"total_cycles": NEVER` be the correct input?
6. I am not sure how the tax part works, why am I the one that gets to modify it?

---

Additional Concerns:

7. The document does not show the live equivalent of the link `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans` is it just simply `https://api.live.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans`?
8. I tried to add the above code using git bash and curl but as I run it it shows `1008{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials are missing"}`
9. Do I try to run the curl code in Git bash and not change my directory? I just start git and run the curl here:

[image: 1]

Any help will be appreciated. I just making sure everything is what needs to be because these three subscriptions will go to a live website. I have to be certain only one subscription runs at a time.

**UPDATE:** I tried making it to `curl -v -X POST https://api.production.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans` and this one is not functionning either.

**UPDATE:** Can anyone show an example of a working curl sample request?

**UPDATE:** at the `-H "Authorization: Basic account_clientid:account_secretcode"`, just to be clear I took out my id code there since I cant just show it in public. An example that I placed there is

```
-H "Authorization: Basic JAKRc85nJy2eMLq3aIV:01PvLC934xMAwLHqU4JqA89as4N"
```

**UPDATE** I tried to run this curl in git after reading the answers so far and somehow I still get and error. I made sure that the api is in api.paypal.com and the client id and secret id is the live version.

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Basic AR7nnwwotKOt4YdcGHZc0P2RVsRT67_Gf2hyrKyDl3ZgCKsikeKbXdQ9Fj-_21v4RulkXsgAASe7_VKv:EKwsdDo1ehtOOOSZCGMu1C9903qr4cQOOZI2rgFYhvugh2SO1V04q9MWY9SXwa352zBt1mGglLuWgR4D" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: MWC-2501E-001" \
-d '{
  "product_id": "ELITE-2501149",
  "name": "Elite Membership",
  "description": "Elite Membership Monthly Plan",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "billing_cycles": [
    {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "MONTH",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
      "sequence": 1,
      "total_cycles": 999,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "149",
          "currency_code": "PHP"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_preferences": {
    "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
    "setup_fee": {
      "value": "0",
      "currency_code": "PHP"
    },
    "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
    "payment_failure_threshold": 3
  },
  "taxes": {
    "percentage": "12",
    "inclusive": false
  }
}'
```

I get this error:

```
100   921  100   159  100   762     99    478  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   578{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"1975a4fe9232","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error","rel":"information_link"}]}
```

[image: 2]

**UPDATE**

Read all the links and followed the steps, I think this is the only issue left

```
{"name":"NOT_AUTHORIZED","message":"Authorization failed due to insufficient permissions.","debug_id":"484a9d7460069","details":[{"issue":"PERMISSION_DENIED","description":"You do not have permission to access or perform operations on this resource"}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#NOT_AUTHORIZED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

I checked the Paypal help center and it seems that I need someone from Paypal itself to authorize my REST.

Comment: Can you add some more information about the specific PayPal product that you are attempting to integrate? At what point is the above script breaking down?

Comment: when I try to trigger this script in my git bash and it is a subscription based plan. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create I already explained it in the question.

Comment: It breaks down and gives me an error in my bash

Comment: About your Concern #8 - you may have forgotten to declare the `account_clientid` and `account_secret`

Comment: I cant exactly show my actual client id and secret id in public, so I took it out just for this post.

Comment: Have you tried using the access token instead? `-H "Authorization: Bearer <Access-Token>" \`

Comment: i did, same issue

Comment: the average number of days in a month is actually `30.4` days. (some months have 28 days, some has 30, some has 31, when you average them, you get 30.4167)

Comment: well yes, but paypal's monthly is fixed at 30

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Q1 - In the access token, do I need to put the `"access_token$production$"` and then the code given?

In your example, you are using Basic authentication scheme. You can use:

```
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token" \
```

But to answer your question, no you don't need to specifically include the `access_token` text string.

---

#### Q2 - Can I manually create the Paypal request id and the product id?

Yes, request id is used so you can retry your API calls.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/reference/api-requests/#http-request-headers

**HOWEVER** product_id should come from https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/catalog-products/v1/#products_create

*so you will need to do it first. See my update at the bottom part of this answer.*

---

#### Q3 - Will the billing cycles be all on the same command or do I have to trigger this three times?

You will need to call each plan configuration to create three subscription plans. Basically, in the API doc example, it shows you it has a billing cycle created for a Trial period and the regular plan it self. It also says:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create

> An array of billing cycles for trial and regular billing. A plan can
>   have multiple billing cycles but only one regular billing cycle.

You also mentioned:

***only one will be active at a time, if a user chooses another of the
three while one is running, they will automatically be stopped getting
billed and will be charged with the new one chosen. (eg: currently
elite149, the subscription and renewal will change to 549luxury once
chosen).***

You'll need to do this programmatically on your end.

If a user unsubscribes to a plan, then you will need to cancel his subscription by calling: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_cancel

If you plan to change subscription, then first you need to cancel existing, then subscribe the user to the new subscription plan using: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

---

#### Q4 - Is the setup fee the charge if a customer subscribes? I first assumed that is the case and set it to 0.

The setup fee is just an add-on fee you can charge your customers. You will need to manually declare this or make it optional by making setup fee value 0.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-payment_preferences

---

#### Q5 - My intention is to have the monthly subscription (30 Days) auto renew until the user unsubscribes. I set my example to 12 but will "total_cycles": NEVER be the correct input?

The maximum value is 999. It only accepts integer.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-billing_cycle

---

#### Q6 - I am not sure how the tax part works, why am I the one that gets to modify it?

Because tax is dependent on what region or country you are in. You are using PHP or Philippine Peso as currency so it could mean that you are in the Philippines. You will need to setup your tax percentage as 12% as that is what is used for taxing goods and services

Source: https://www.full-suite.com/blog/whats-difference-vat-percentage-tax/

Paypal tax object definition: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#definition-taxes

---

#### Q7 - The document does not show the live equivalent of the link `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans` is it just simply `https://api.live.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans?`

You can find the addresses here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

It says:

> Sandbox: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com
>
> Live: https://api.paypal.com

---

#### Q8 - I tried to add the above code using git bash and curl but as I run it it shows `1008{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials are missing"}`

It could mean either mean that you are passing invalid credentials. Make sure that you are sending them via the headers using

```
Bearer <Access-Token>
```

or

```
Basic <client_id>:<secret>
```

And verify that your string input represents the actual values.
Also, make sure you are using Sandbox credentials as it has a different set of credentials from the production or live
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb-create-accounts/#create-a-sandbox-account

---

#### Q9 - Do I try to run the curl code in Git bash and not change my directory? I just start git and run the curl here:

Do not misinterpret Git Bash as the command line interface, it is simply a versioning tool for your projects. However the Git Package for windows has built-in components that should allow you to run CURL. **Since Curl is installed in the Bin directory, *you should be able to run it on any directory*.**

You can run the curl command using different tools ideally using a scripting or programming language like PHP, Phyton, Java or even Node which has better support for curl and should allow you to write and test your program easier in a neater way.

---

## UPDATE

I've investigated on this further. I thought I'd share it with you because it seems you haven't read the whole API document yet.

You are creating Subscription plans however you'll need to Create the products first. (I have updated my answer to Question #2)

**First - Create the Product**
This will create the product_id you need to create your subscription plans.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/catalog-products/v1/#products_create
To go back and check the product you created an get its product id, you can use this api call:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/catalog-products/v1/#products_list

**Then - Create The Subscription Plan**
After you have created your products, you can then create multiple subscription plans for it.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create

**Moving forward**, if you want to subscribe / unsubscribe users you'll need to programatically do it as per my answer to Question #3.

### About your problem with invalid credentials

Try getting the access token first. To do that follow instructions here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/get-an-access-token-curl/

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token \
   -H "Accept: application/json" \
   -H "Accept-Language: en_US" \
   -u "client_id:secret" \
   -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Then get the token returned and use that to make your api calls.
It will return something like this:

```
{
  "scope": "scope",
  "access_token": "Access-Token",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "app_id": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
  "expires_in": 31349,
  "nonce": "nonce"
}
```

Here is a modified version of your code that I used to test, notice it uses `Bearer token` instead `basic client_id:secret`

```
curl -v -X POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/plans \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token-goeshere" \
-H "PayPal-Request-Id: MWC-helper" \
-d '{
  "product_id": "PROD-ELITETEST", //<---- this product id should be taken from the real product id when you created your product through product_create api.
  "name": "Elite Membership",
  "description": "Elite Membership Monthly Plan",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "billing_cycles": [
    {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "MONTH",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
      "sequence": 1,
      "total_cycles": 999,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "149",
          "currency_code": "PHP"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "payment_preferences": {
    "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
    "setup_fee": {
      "value": "0",
      "currency_code": "PHP"
    },
    "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
    "payment_failure_threshold": 3
  },
  "taxes": {
    "percentage": "12",
    "inclusive": false
  }
}'
```

It worked for me!

Comment: how come the example in create subscription includes customer info when I am still just trying to create the plan and trying to trigger the unsubscribe?

Comment: @ButtonPress you might be confusing create_plan with create_subscription

Create subscription - is when the customer subscribes to a billing plan.

Comment: tried again based on the answers you gave, i still get an error. If possible I would like a working exampled on the three subscriptions.

Comment: @ButtonPress

**Create plan** - is the process of creating your billing plans so paypal understands what plans are available for subscription. This also lets you configure each plan.

**Create subscription** - is when the customer subscribes to a billing plan, it requires you to enter the plan id which can be returned after you create your plans.

To list all of your available plans to get their ids, you may call plans_list https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_list

Comment: Are you using Sandbox credentials? I've updated my answer for Question #8, you'll need a different set of credentials for accessing Sandbox API, that could be the reason why it is returning `invalid credentials`

Comment: @ButtonPress ok, that is an internal error that you'll need to ask from Paypal as there is no way to find out what happened. Problem could be on their end. You can submit a support ticket indicating that you received the error and include the debug id. 
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/s/?language=en_US

You can also check if all API status is operational by visiting: https://www.paypal-status.com

Comment: @ButtonPress also you should not be testing with the live API so instead use Sandbox, when you login to your Paypal developer dashboard, check your sandbox account and get the credentials from there, if none you'll need to create them then use the sandbox api address to continue testing. The dashboard also provides you list of API calls you made and the debug ids it created.

Comment: not im not sure anymore what else is missing with my request, I used api.sandbox.paypal.com and made sure also that the client id and secret is the sanbox one. I still get "error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client credentials are missing"

Comment: @ButtonPress I have updated my answer, you should use Bearer <Access-Token>, also you will need to create your product first so you can substitute for your product_id field or else you will get `{"name":"RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","message":"The specified resource does not exist.","debug_id":"2a6261d2423c0","details":[{"issue":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","description":"Invalid product id"}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}`

Comment: thank you for elaborating even more on your answer, now my request is blocked because it says my REST app is missing some required permissions. I am trying to get PayPal support to fix this.